# "now" mind units control not displaying correctly

Tags: ingress

I have two "control field active"
I own all the portals and resonators for 1 field.
and 66% of the resonators for the second field.

Yet my "now" shows Mind Unit Control as zero.
I even waited for a checkpoint to no avail.

Any explanations?

Comment: You were the player that created the final link that built the field, correct? That's the player that gets credit for the field. Portal ownership doesn't factor in.

Comment: @Koviko the 'now' tab is a whole other animal, resonator ownership is he primary factor for the stats there.

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting, I've found that if I have "restrict background data" checkmarked on ANY of things owned by Google, it will affect ALL the Google apps including Ingress.

Unchecking this option on all my apps fixed the problem.